# Extend the login timeout in a ASP NET 7 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

My ASP Core web application was recently upgraded from NET6 to NET7. Almost zero problems except one, which still puzzles me.

With the "old" NET6 version, once an user log then app in (**without** the "remember me" flag), his/her access was granted for several hours. I never measured exactly how lasted, but I remember pretty well that you were asked to log in again only the day later.

This behavior was even leaving the page in "idle" for some hour. You could leave your morning job and continue your work in the afternoon without any trouble.

Once I switched to NET7, that behavior misteriously changed, even no code was touched.

Now, if you leave the session idle for 20+ minutes, you'll be asked to log in again. That seems what the docs say: the user session expires after 20 mins, hence the login is sticked to the session.

To me, I wonder **HOW** could be work differently with NET6, but that's another story.

That being said, our customers often forget to tick the "remember me" flag and don't like the "new" shortened timeout. Practical usage may face a few-minutes app usage, then a some- hour of pause. Being forced to login every time is very annoying.

Docs say that the "remember me" flag state summarizes the internal behavior as follows:

- when NOT checked, the login sticks to the user session, hence it
  lasts 20 mins when idle;
- when checked, the login sticks to a cookie,
  whose expiration is pre-configured (typically 14 days).

My naive attempt to solve the problem is using a cookie even when the flag is not checked. To achieve that, I derived the `SignInManager<UserAccount>` and patched the actual login entry as follows:

```
public sealed class CustomSignInManager
    : SignInManager<UserAccount>
{
    // ctor

    public override Task SignInWithClaimsAsync(
        UserAccount user, 
        AuthenticationProperties? authenticationProperties, 
        IEnumerable<Claim> additionalClaims
        )
    {
        authenticationProperties ??= new();
        if (authenticationProperties.IsPersistent == false)
        {
            authenticationProperties.IsPersistent = true;
            authenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        }

        return base.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, authenticationProperties, additionalClaims);
    }

}
```

Finally, the questions: is all that a decent yet reliable solution? are there better and clever ways to achieve that?

Comment: are you using session `app.UseSession()` in the `Startup`? the other question, why didn't you just make `remember me` checked by default, thus, a user can untick if it does not want to be remembered. (I don't encourage the idea of non-expired sessions, as it opens some security risks, and should be avoided).

Comment: @iSR5 no, I don't use `UseSession`. I tried with almost no result, but I also would avoid to "alter" the standard behavior for only one particular feature. That being said, I agree with you about the risks, but I also noticed that most of the common used portals offers a pretty long login timeout. I mind just the bank portal having a few minutes expiration.